# How to insert data into SQL Server with other form values (addwithvalue)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code:

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO fiscal(itemcode, itemname, price) 
      SELECT itemcode, itemname, price FROM inventorymaster
      WHERE itemcode = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", label1.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.close();
```

Why doesn't this code work? Actually it doesn't insert my `label1.Text;`

Comment: You are missing a ", also this is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Thank you Sir. Where exactly should i place a "?

Comment: You're not using your `@username` parameter anywhere in your SQL statement! How should this code insert something you're not using in your SQL?!??!?

Comment: (1) Your code is wide open to SQL injection.  (2) You're trying to add a *label*'s text as a parameter, instead of an actual user input element.  (3) Your SQL query doesn't *have* a parameter, so why are you trying to add one?  (It *should* though, see item (1) above for why.)

Comment: You also probably need another Paramater for your query variable`"INSERT INTO fiscal(itemcode,itemname,price) 
select itemcode,itemname,price from inventorymaster
where itemcode = @icode"` Then you'd add another `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@icode", textBox1.Text);`. You don't seem to be using the @username parameter at all.

Comment: Just after the = in your where clause

Comment: Thank you Sir It worked. I understood your example.